# How to write a select query that returns data that is older than a month specifically using EPOCH?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, epoch

Need to write select query that returns data that is older than a month and I need to use EPOCH.

```
select *   
from TABLE 
where DATE < (NOW() - 604800)      <- does not work.
```

I don't understand why SQL Server would not have something this basic.

Comment: where DATE > dateadd(month, -1, getdate())

Comment: you can use `second` instead of `month` if you need that

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's easier in SQL Server: you can achieve what you want to do with the following query;

```
select * from Table where Date < DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I already tried this approach, but I realized where the issue is "after" posting the question. I did not create the table and assumed that the field was a DATE type. The data type in that field was actually INT and hence the conversion did not work. I tried to use CAST, but that conversion does not return EPOC.

Comment: This works: 
select * from TABLE where StatusDate <= (Select DateDiff(S, '19700101', dateadd(month, -1, GetDate()))